# How do I populate the initialState in Redux from react native's AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage, react-native-web

I have a React Native app. I am storing username and uid in AsyncStorage so they don't have to log in every time. How do I populate the initialState with these values. There are some packages that do it for you but it seems like this should be doable without the overhead of another package. Right now initial state is just empty values.

```
const initialState = {
  uid: "",
  username: "",
};
```

Comment: You could manually implement a system that rehydrates your Redux state on app start from AsyncStorage but libraries such as redux persist already have this

Comment: I'm fairly new to React/Redux. How would I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. Just create an action that gets the AsyncStorage properties and dispatch the array of properties to the reducer where they are assigned to the state. And you call the action directly on the store. Much lighter than adding a whole other library. For simplicity I'll assume all the Redux code is in one file called myRedux.js:

```js
// Imports:
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { AsyncStorage, } from "react-native";

// Set initial state to empty values:
const initialState = {
  uid: "",
  username: "",
};

// Reducer: 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "setInit":
      return { 
        ...state, 
        uid: action.uid,
        username: action.username,
      }

    default: 
      return state;
  }
};

// Store
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export { store };

// Action
const setInit = (result) => {
  return {
    type: "setInit",
    uid: result[0][1],
    username: result[1][1],
  };
} 

const getAsyncStorage = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(['uid', 'username'])
    .then((result) => {dispatch(setInit(result))});
  };
};

// Dispatch the getAsyncStorage() action directly on the store.
store.dispatch(getAsyncStorage());
```

Then in the Screen files you can access them with mapStateToProps:

```jsx
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    uid: state.uid,
    username: state.username,
  };
}

// Access the prop values in the render:
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Uid: {this.props.uid}</Text> 
      <Text>Username: {this.props.username}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

// Connect mapStateToProps to the component class
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aman Mittal provides an excellent guide for persisting state to `AsyncStorage` and populating the initial state using the `redux-persist` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-native-with-asyncstorage/

Just make sure when you get to the `config` part, that you use `AsyncStorage` as the `storage` value:

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import rootReducer from './reducers';


...

export const config = {
    key: 'my-root-key',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: [],
};

const store = createStore(
  persistReducer(
    config,
    rootReducer
  ),
  compose(...activeEnhancers),
);
```